# How to merge select option name in php

Tags: php, html

http://10.10.55.25/test/index.php?getdate=2018&getdate=05

i have 2 dropdown option. Year and month. the result after i click search is "getdate=2018&getdate=05" but i want the result is "getdate=201805"

```
<?php
    echo "<select name=getdate>";
    for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
    {
    $year=date('Y',strtotime("last day of -$i year"));
    echo "<option>$year</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<select name=getdate>";
    for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++){
    $month=date('m',strtotime("first day of -$i month"));
    echo "<option>$month</option> ";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo "Search";?></button>
```

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sM1f.jpg)

Comment: you need to have hidden input and JS to concatenate year and month values for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have hidden input and JS to concatenate year and month values for that

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<select id='year'>";
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
{
$year=date('Y',strtotime("last day of -$i year"));
echo "<option>$year</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select id='month'>";
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++){
$month=date('m',strtotime("first day of -$i month"));
echo "<option>$month</option> ";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

<input type="hidden" name="getdate">
<button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo "Search";?></button>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select#year, select#month').change(function() {
    yr = $('select#year option:selected').text();
    mnth = $('select#month option:selected').text();

    $('input[name="getdate"]').val(yr+""+mnth);
});
</script>
```